How i Open my mobile app in Background mode flutter with firebase notification
I tired to open app in background mode in flutter with firebase notification .But it's not working.
what I do for achieve anyone can help me.
Thank You...
I will create outside overlay custome notification in my app .that working foreground mode but its not working app closing state .i will click on the custome notification button that time i will raise firebase notification the lisen the notification in app foreground mode  its will work. What can i do for my app working closing state.
I expect whene i click overlay custome notification button that time raised firebase notification and lisen background mode this step until working but I used Navigator syntax like Navigator.push then its throw some exception Like below
No MediaQuery widget ancestor found. Scaffold widgets require a MediaQuery widget ancestor
Please Help Me
thank you

"Questions seeking debugging help ('why isn't this code working?') must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example." and Build a minimal, complete, reproducible example
